# Why Docker exec need --interactive? --tty should be enough?

Tags: docker

I new to docker, when i play with `docker exec`. I have below question:

Command  `docker exec -t 26b318e534c0 bash`, already have tty, this should be interactive? Why must use `docker exec **-it** 26b318e534c0 bash`?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a pseudo tty without any input to the tty device. This allows an application generating output to do so using content recognized by the tty device (e.g. color output). If you want to be able to interactively type in that tty, then you need to pass the input option, from a terminal with tty support (not from a shell script, and not from some windows command prompts), to attach your console to the stdin of that container.

---

As a simple example with `docker run`, these two commands will look different:

```
docker run -t --rm debian ls -al --color=always

docker run --rm debian ls -al --color=always
```

The first will have color output, the second will not, and neither will allow you to type input to the `ls` command being run inside the container.